# react js not rendering properly after removing item from list

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, list, react-redux

i am trying to remove item on click from a list in react js. but i click on delete button it remove the last item from list not the one i clicked. if i check in console.log it show the correct output but not rendering it correctly.
i have tried to remove item in many different ways . here is my codesandbox link for poroject
https://9o0jw.csb.app/
i don't know what i am doing wrong
here is my code snippet

```
{projects &&
            projects.map((project, key) => (
              <div
                key={`editProject-${key}`}
                className="d-sm-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-2"
              >
                <div className="flex-sm-fill">
                  <div className="project-input-field">
                    <input type="text" defaultValue={project.title} />
                  </div>
                  <div className="project-input-field">
                    <input type="url" defaultValue={project.link} />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="remove-project">
                  <button onClick={() => removeProject(project.title)}>
                    Remove Projoect
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
```

And here is delete function

```
 const removeProject = title => {
    // let newProjects = projects;
    // newProjects = newProjects.filter(project => project.title !== title);
    // setProjects(newProjects);
    setProjects(prevProject => {
      return prevProject.filter(pro => pro.title !== title);
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd look at `` key={`editProject-${key}`} `` - you're using the array index so react thinks that the removed key is the last index when it re-renders. If the `project.title` is unique, then use that as the `key`.

However if `project.title` is not unique, then look to create a unique `id` when a `project` is created.

More info https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem even after using a unique `id` during filter.

Considering the time of the question you probably already solved it, but for future resarchers, a solution for me was creating a state for holding the id onclick the element. First make sure you have a unique id to also use it as key, then something like this may work.

```
const [clickedID, setClickedID] = useState(0);

const removeProject = (id) => {
    setClickedID(id)
    const filteredProjects = project.filter(pro => pro.id !== clickedID)
    setProjects(filteredProjects);
    });
  };
```